# コレクションビューのスクロールで、オートレイアウトが、更新されることはありますか？

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

コレクションビューをスクロールすると、
他のビューのレイアウトが変わってしまいます。

コレクションビューのスクロールで、
オートレイアウトが、
更新されることはありますか？

このタイミングで、
`viewDidLayoutSubviews`が呼ばれます。

デバイスを回転した後の
一回だけこのような挙動となります。